# Environment variables fork that works under IDEA doesn't works in console or in build.sbt setting

Tags: linux, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, environment-variables

I'm working to a project under Linux, with IDEA, in Scala.
I have two environment variables needed for my project.
If I set them in IDEA, from Edit Configuration - Environment variables:

```
SERVICE_CFG_BASE_FILE=/home/dev/.../aaa.json;LOCAL_IPS={localhost.ipv4:0.0.0.0}
```

The project runs ok.
If I remove them from IDEA and try to add them to the project from build.sbt:

```
  .settings(fork in Test := true)
  .settings(envVars in Test ++= Map(
    "SERVICE_CFG_BASE_FILE" -> "/home/dev/.../aaa.json",
    "LOCAL_IPS" -> "{localhost.ipv4:0.0.0.0}"))
```

The Environment variables doesn't initialize properly and the app does not start.

Also, if I try to initialize them from console:

```
$ export SERVICE_CFG_BASE_FILE=/home/dev/.../aaa.json;LOCAL_IPS={localhost.ipv4:0.0.0.0}
```

If I try to see if they are initialized:

```
echo $SERVICE_CFG_BASE_FILE
echo $LOCAL_IPS
```

The result is good but when I try to run the app:

```
$ sbt run
```

The app doesn't start...

Comment: Everything looks OK with your _SBT_ property configuration. When you say the _"variables doesn't initialize properly and the app does not start"_ is that from running just _SBT_ (without using _IntelliJ_)?

Comment: No, both IntelliJ (if I remove them from Enviroment Variables) and from console gives me the same error (as there are no good config in build.sbt)... Somehow, it doesn't recognize those variables... It works only if I set them in IDEA, but I can't deliver the app like that...

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that `sbt test` fails, or that `sbt run` fails? You're only defining these variables in `Test` scope, so they will not be defined when you run your code (unless they are pre-defined in your Linux environemnt). How are you retrieving the environment variables in your code?

Comment: sbt run fails, but I also tried to set them as .settings(fork in (Test, run) := true) .settings(envVars in (Test, run) ++= Map(...  I'm retrieving them with  val baseFile = sys.env.get("SERVICE_CFG_BASE_FILE")...

Comment: What values do `sys.env.get(...)` return? It should be an `Option[String]` value, correct?

Comment: OK. I did some testing and found something weird. If you scope these properties `(Test, run)` then then the environment variables are not defined, and/or the `fork` property doesn't take effect. (I experimented with each combination.) However, if you scope these properties individually, (that is `fork in Test := true`, `fork in run := true`, `envVars in Test ++= Map(...)`, `envVars in run ++= Map(...)`, then both test and runtime environment variables are defined.

Comment: Can you put the output from `sbt test` and `sbt run` in your question? BTW, in case you're not aware, you can add all the properties as part of a single `.settings(...)` block.

Comment: You're right, after I put it separate lines for Test/run - for fork - envVars, in console, sbt run works but it still gives me errors in IDEA. But it's ok, because in IDEA I can use the enviroment variables. In console is what I wanted to work. Thanks!

Comment: You can configure _IntelliJ_ to build, test, run, etc. using _SBT_. In that case, it should still work, and you don't have to define any environment variables in _IntelliJ_.